# Ubuntu 20.10 on Intel NUC5CPYH

Tags: boot, drivers, intel

I'm new to Linux and wanted to give it a try. First steps are not being very easy.

- System: Intel NUC5CPYH
- OS: Ubuntu 20.10 (also tried with Pop!_OS 20.10)
- Connection: HDMI cable directly to a BENQ 4K display

**Problem**: I'm able to install it without problem, but when booting for the first time I get a black screen and mouse freeze before the user login.

Here is what I've done:

- Updated NUC BIOS to version 079
- Changed BIOS configuration to "Linux"
- Changed definition in GRUB where I set `nomodeset` (this allows me to boot but the resolution of the display is terrible)
- Found a [link](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-graphics-drivers-for-intel-nuc-de3815tyke) with a possible solution where I installed intel drivers (no success)

I've attached a screenshot of the last command on the link above in the hope that it helps (honestly I can't make much sense of it).

Output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

[image: Screenshot of output of glxinfo | grep OpenGL in terminal]

Comment: It sounds to me like a problem with X. I assume you can ssh into the machine, or bring it up single-user and get a shell prompt? Look in /var/log/Xorg.log, see if anything obvious is happening there, or may be post that so that one of us can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a different approach. I've installed Lubuntu on the machine and it is working without any problems. Probably since it is an old machine it struggles with the more heavy distributions. I also purchased a new NUC, 10th generation and have managed to install Pop!_OS 20.04 without any problem.

Now I have two NUCs with different distributions, the old one I will try to use for long operations that require some time (e.g. uploading data to a backup server) and the new one as my daily use machine.